# Proving $A$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof behind showing a set is a subset of another set, but I'm struggle to do so.

Can some one help using this example to show:

$A \subseteq B$?

Here

$A = \{x | x = 4n + 3,  n \in \mathbb{N}\}$,

$B = \{x | x = 2n+1,  n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Your subset relation is backward.  For the sets you define, $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't hold that $B \subseteq A$, but $A \subseteq B$.

In order to show this, we pick a $x \in A$. Then $x$ is of the form $x=4n+3$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$x=4n+3=2(2n+1)+1$.

$n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $2n+1$ also belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.

So $x$ is of the form $2m+1, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and thus $x \in B$.

Comment: What about to show for an Arbitrary Set?

Comment: If you want to show that $A \subseteq B$ then you pick an element that belongs to $A$ and you try to show that it also belongs to $B$. @RandomMath

Comment: I don't really understand how you concluded 2m+1, would you be able to briefly explain?

Comment: @RandomMath We concluded that $x=2(2n+1)+1$. $$$$
$n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $2n+1$ also belongs to $\mathbb{N}$. ( I have set $m=2n+1$.)

Comment: @RandomMath Did you get it?

Comment: im going through it, just trying to understand how you got to this line "x = 4n + 3 = 2(2n + 1) + 1"

Comment: $x=4n+3=2 \cdot 2 \cdot n+2+1=2(2n+1)+1$ @RandomMath

Comment: Oh I understand what you have done now! So for any type of set, do I try to see if I can get that equation out of that set? And if I do (like above) it is a subset?

Comment: It depends on the sets that you have. For example suppose that you want to show that $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 18 \mid x \} \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$. Then you could proceed as follows:
$$$$
We suppose that $a \in \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}: 18 \mid x \}$. So we have that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $18 \mid a$. By definition of divisibility, there is an integer $y$ such that $a=18y$. Since $6 \mid 18 \Rightarrow 6 \mid 18y \Rightarrow 6 \mid a$. Thus, $a$ is one of the integers that $6$ divides, so $a \in \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$.

Comment: Therefore, $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} :18 \mid x \} \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following sets $A$={$1,2,3,4,5$}, $B$= {$1,2,3$}. Then we can see that every element (an element is a member of the set) of $B$ is also in $A$ Then we say that $B$ is a subset of $A$. More generally speaking, if every element of set $B$ is in a set $A$ then we say $B$ is a subset of $A$ and denote it by $B \subset A$

With regards to your question we have to show that every element in A is in B (You have your relation the wrong way around). So pick an element in $A$ which is of the form $4n+3$ where $n$ is any natural number, then we can show that $4n+3 = 2(2n+1)+1$, where $2n+1$ is our natural number and you see that every element in A takes the form of an element in $B$ and hence it also belongs to $B$ and thus we conclude it is a subset of $B$